# Itirate through array, and run function on each value

Tags: php

I need to iterate through an array, and edit each value but not differently.

```
<?php
Function parseStatus($Input, $Start, $End){
    $String = " " . $Input;
    $Init = StrPos($String, $Start);

    If($Init == 0){
        Return '';
    }

    $Init += StrLen($Start);
    $Length = StrPos($String, $End, $Init) - $Init;

    Return SubStr($String, $Init, $Length);
}

Function getAllStatuses($Username){
    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->validateOnParse = True;
    @$DOM->loadHtml(File_Get_Contents('http://lifestream.aol.com/stream/' . $Username));
    $xPath = new DOMXPath($DOM);

    $Stream = $DOM->getElementById('stream')->nodeValue; // return stream content for display name
    $Nodes = $xPath->query('//div[@class="stream"]');

    $Name = Explode(' ', Trim($Stream));
    $User = $Name[0];

    $Statuses = Array();

    ForEach($Nodes as $Node){
        ForEach($Node->getElementsByTagName('li') as $Key => $Tags){
            $Statuses[] = $Tags->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    ForEach($Statuses as $Status){
        If(StrPos($Status, 'Services')){
            Echo 'services is definitely in there';
            $New = AIM::parseStatus($Status, $User, 'Services');
            Echo $New;
            Break;
        }
    }
?>
```

The issue is, $New only echos the very first output, but how do I get that to run through each value in the array, and do the same thing?

Expected output:
[name as start] what i need [word Services]

Then on each value in the array, do the same thing so it'd be like:

what i need

again what i need but different string

etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: remove the Break; from it..

Comment: ... I just shook my head at that LOL... Thanks again, I'm sorry smh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Break;` in your `foreach` loop is, well, breaking the loop.

Remove the `Break;` and it should work.

Have a read here:
http://www.php.net/break

> break ends execution of the current for, foreach, while, do-while or switch structure.

Comment: Thanks to Hardy I realized that, I was overthinking this one.